# FullSimplify is taking very long line to evaluate a simple expression

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

Doing `FullSimplify[ToRadicals[res, Assumptions -> assum], assum]` is taking too much time for a simple expression. Am I doing something wrong? Is there anything I can do to make it finish?

Here's the full code, everything runs fast until the `FullSimplify`:

```
assum = 0 < v < c && L > 0 && t > 0 && x > 0 && a > 0 && 
   0 < cmedium < c && c > 2 v && 1 <= n < c && n >= 1;

b = v/c
g = 1/Sqrt[(1 - b^2)]
cmedium = c/n + v (1 - 1/n^2);

t1s = Solve[t == Sqrt[(L/g + v*t)^2 + (x - a)^2]/cmedium && assum, t]
res = Normal[t /. First@t1s]

FullSimplify[ToRadicals[res, Assumptions -> assum], assum]
```

Comment: Why do you need the output in radicals instead of a Root object? And what's wrong with using Solve without assumptions, e.g., `Simplify[Solve[t == Sqrt[(L/g + v*t)^2 + (x - a)^2]/cmedium, 
  t], assum]`

Comment: Without assumptions I get two roots, I need only the positive one (t>0). If I use the assumption I get the positive, but I get the Root object... To share and better visualize the result I don't understand why can't Mathematica show the result without the Root object, when it apparently obviously exists... (the Root object is unnecessarily complex). I know I can Solve and choose the second solution manually, that I know is the positive one. But I was looking forward to Mathematica doing this.

Answer (score 3):

I won't address why [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) returns a [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) object when given assumptions. Instead, I will suggest that you can instead programmatically determine which solution returned by [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) without assumptions is positive. First, the solution from a simple [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
b = v/c;
g = 1/Sqrt[(1-b^2)];
cmedium = c/n + v (1-1/n^2);
sol = t /. Solve[t == Sqrt[(L/g + v*t)^2 + x^2]/cmedium, t];
```

Then, use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) to check which solution is positive:

```
Reduce[sol[[1]] > 0 && 0<v<c && a>0 && x>0 && L>0 && n>0]
```

False

So, the second solution is the only one that can be positive. After simplification:

```
FullSimplify[sol[[2]], 0<v<c && a>0 && x>0 && L>0 && n>0]
```

> $\frac{n^2 \left(L n^2 v \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{(c-v) (c+v) \left(c L n+L \left(n^2-1\right)
>    v\right)^2}{c^2}+x^2 (c n-v) (n (c+2 n v)-v)}\right)}{(c n-v) (n (c+2 n v)-v)}$

the same as your answer.

Comment: +1. Somehow, when I see your answers and it's also something I know how to do, I think, yep, that's kinda the way I'd do it.  I give a variant in my answer.  If you simplify the reduction of `sol[[2]] > 0` as in your answer, it will simplify to `True` as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way (`Simplify[Reduce[assum \[Implies] cond,...], assum]` seems to often work for me):

```
sol = Solve[t == Sqrt[(L/g + v*t)^2 + (x - a)^2]/cmedium, t];
Simplify[
 Hold@Reduce[Implies[assum, t > 0], {}, Reals] /. sol // ReleaseHold,
 assum]
{pos} = Pick[sol, %]
(*
  {False, True}   <-- nonpositive, positive

  {{t -> (2 L n^4 v Sqrt[((c - v) (c + v))/c^2] +
      √((4 L^2 n^8 (c - v) v^2 (c + v))/c^2 + 
         4 n^4 (c^2 n^2 - 2 c n v + 2 c n^3 v + v^2 - 
            2 n^2 v^2) (a^2 + L^2 - (L^2 v^2)/c^2 - 2 a x + 
            x^2)))/(2 (c^2 n^2 - 2 c n v + 2 c n^3 v + v^2 - 2 n^2 v^2))}}
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround. Because I know the 2nd solution is the positive, I can choose

```
assum = 0 < v < c && L > 0 && t > 0 && x > 0 && a > 0 && 
   0 < cmedium < c && c > 2 v && 1 <= n < c && n >= 1 && c > 1;

b = v/c;
g = 1/Sqrt[(1 - b^2)];
cmedium = c/n + v (1 - 1/n^2);

t1s = Solve[t == Sqrt[(L/g + v*t)^2 + (x)^2]/cmedium, t]
t1 = FullSimplify[t /. t1s[[2]], assume]
```

which outputs

$$
\left\{\left\{t\to \frac{2 L n^4 v \sqrt{\frac{(c-v) (c+v)}{c^2}}-\sqrt{\frac{4 L^2 n^8 v^2 (c-v) (c+v)}{c^2}+4 n^4 \left(c^2 n^2+2 c n^3 v-2 c n v-2 n^2 v^2+v^2\right) \left(-\frac{L^2 v^2}{c^2}+L^2+x^2\right)}}{2 \left(c^2 n^2+2 c n^3 v-2 c n v-2 n^2 v^2+v^2\right)}\right\},\left\{t\to \frac{\sqrt{\frac{4 L^2 n^8 v^2 (c-v) (c+v)}{c^2}+4 n^4 \left(c^2 n^2+2 c n^3 v-2 c n v-2 n^2 v^2+v^2\right) \left(-\frac{L^2 v^2}{c^2}+L^2+x^2\right)}+2 L n^4 v \sqrt{\frac{(c-v) (c+v)}{c^2}}}{2 \left(c^2 n^2+2 c n^3 v-2 c n v-2 n^2 v^2+v^2\right)}\right\}\right\}
$$

choosing the 2nd solution and simplifying:

$$
\frac{L n^4 v \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}+\sqrt{n^4 \left(\frac{(c-v) (c+v) \left(c L n+L \left(n^2-1\right) v\right)^2}{c^2}+x^2 (c n-v) (n (c+2 n v)-v)\right)}}{(c n-v) (n (c+2 n v)-v)}
$$